# Having trouble finding socket and wiring harness for xb 2005 left blinker

Tags: headlight, wiring, scion, replacements

So I recently ordered new headlights from O'reilly, and when I received them the blinker sockets did not come with them. I think I found the socket, but all the plugins I come across are for the main headlamp.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The part you are looking for can be found in the aftermarket from a company called Airtex. The PN is: **AIRTEX / WELLS 1P2139 {#1507}** ... You can find it on [RockAuto.com](http://www.rockauto.com/en/parts/airtex+/+wells,1P2139,turn+signal+lamp+socket,4024). Here is a copy of their picture:

[image]